# Pass range object as parameter to QUERY function in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, range

In a Google Sheet I have this query:

```
= QUERY( Data!A1:M300, "select A,B,C,D where C <= date '" & TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND D >= date '" & TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'", 0)
```

What I would like to do now is make the first parameter of the QUERY function dynamic. For this I wrote this small function:

```
function getDataRange(sheetName) {

  if (sheetName == "") {
    sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName)

  if (sheet != null) {

    output = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  } else {

    output = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  }

  return output

}
```

Now if I pass this function as a first parameter to QUERY like this

```
= QUERY( getDataRange("Data"), "select A,B,C,D where C <= date '" & TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND D >= date '" & TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'", 0)
```

I get this error

```
"Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A"
```

I have not found a way to pass a dynamic range as the first parameter to the QUERY function and I am very thankful for any hint.

Comment: Try changing your select clause to: "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col3 <= date '" & TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND Col3 >= date '" & TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick.

Comment: I added the above as an answer for future visitors of this thread. Feel free to accept or upvote it. Cheers, JP

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your select clause to:

```
"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col3 <= date '" & TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND Col3 >= date '" & TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
```